# Convert char[] variable to uintptr_t variable C++

Tags: c++

I have a variable of type char [] with an address. Example: char addr[11] = "0x01234567";. How do I convert this variable to type uintptr_t?

I want it to be equivalent to `uintptr_t add = 0x01234567;`.

Comment: I want it to be equivalent to: uintptr_t add = 0x01234567;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"0x01234567"` is a textual representation of an integer. `std::uintptr_t` is an integer type. You can use any standard formatted input functions to do the conversion. There are several options, but I recommend starting with a string stream.

Comment: I figured out sstream, everything works fine!